# Storyboard blank after deleting and replacing file Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I accidentally deleted my storyboard from Xcode and 'put it back' from the trash on my computer. Now, the app still runs fine and shows all necessary elements as it was left, however the .storyboard file in Xcode is showing up completely blank for all views now so I cannot edit anything on it. If I add an element, it will show up on the final product but nothing existing before the storyboard file was deleted is showing up. Would love to know how to fix this.

Comment: seems like a rendering bug. Try asking forums @ apple

Comment: check you bundle in finder for Base.lprog folder. By default storyboard is present there. If yes then add in your project bundle from xcode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reverting the size class in a storyboard to sizeclass which you designed your views originally in storyboard. [image]

Comment: Perfect, missed this originally!

Comment: Voted up! It's hard to find this in first place.